# Didn't Understand Relationship - How To Find Child Relationship Name?

Tags: soql, custom-object, query, childrecords, childrelationship

I have a many-to many relationship between three objects. LGFProducts, PartsinProducts, and Parts. PartsinProducts is the junction object. I want to be able to get data like the names of the parts that are related to the selected LGFProduct.

I understand that parent-child relationship can only traverse one level down while grandchild-grandpa can travel 5 levels at most. What is the parent-child or child-parent in a many-to-many relationship?

I assumed that I should be traversing upwards from Parts to the junction object partsinproduct and then LGFProducts? But my friend who is not a Salesforce expert but has knowledge in CS said that I should do a parent-child query (of LGFProducts to partsinproduct) to child-parent relationship query (PartsinProduct to Parts). Or perhaps both of these options are wrong and another is appropriate.

Also, I am having a little trouble traversing for custom objects. I understand that I need to append the letter r instead of c but get confused. For example, this is my attempt at a three level upward traversal that fails.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Parts__r.PartsinProducts__r,LGFProducts__r.Name
FROM Parts__c
```

Also if three levels of upward traversal are needed, could one provide an example with custom relationships? As seen above, I am having difficulty successfully querying a three level upward traversal statement for custom objects.

This is my attempt at the parent-child relationship query of LGFProduct to PartsinProducts:

```
SELECT Name,
  (
    SELECT Name
    FROM PartsinProduct__r
  )
FROM LGFProduct__c
```

I am then given this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relationship name is likely `PartsinProducts__r`, which would make your query:

```
SELECT (SELECT Name FROM PartsinProducts__r) FROM LGFProduct__c
```

The way you can check:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.LGFProduct__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == PartsinProduct__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

Copy the output of the above script verbatim and replace `PartsinProducts__r` if that is not the correct relationship name.

Comment: Why does SELECT Name in the first part make the query not work. How do I know when to not have a field and when to have a field, as most examples in the Salesforce SOQL guide does have an field after the select. Also, for the second code script how do I test it? Do I put the code in the query editor?

Comment: @user Yeah don't test it, just run it once in `Execute Anonymous` so you can write the proper query. As for when to include/not include a field, you can think of the entire subquery (`(SELECT Name FROM PartsinProducts__r)`) as one *field* so to speak. You include sub-queries in your outer `SELECT` clause just like you would any other field.

Comment: Also one more question, in my specific case what should I be doing? An upward traversal of grandchild-grandpa or what my friend recommended a parent-child and then a child-parent query for my many to many relationship?

Comment: @user Hmm, it's hard to say what you're after exactly, but you can actually query parent data from the junction, e.g. `(SELECT Parts__r.Name FROM PartsinProducts__r)`, assuming the lookup has an API Name of `Parts__c`.

Comment: We can [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44397/relationships) if you're still confused.