# How to query parent to child (custom objects)

Tags: apex, soql, query, custom-object

I have a problem, comparable articles here don't help me.

I try to query from parent (Proposal__c) to child (EquipmentProposal__c)

```
[Select Id, (Select Equipment__c, Quantity__c, Price__c 
             From EquipmentProposal__r) 
From Proposal__c 
Where Id = : currentProposalId];
```

In the end I have this problem

> "**Didn't understand relationship 'EquipmentProposal__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name.**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a parent-child subquery, you need to use the [child relationship name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm).

In many cases, it will simply be the plural of the child object name + '__r' (so `EquipmentProposals__r` would be the first thing to try).

There are a few ways to get the child relationship name if it's not the plural like looking at the field definition for the relationship field on the child object (you may need to go to the edit screen for the field), or [by using the field describe information](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137949/didnt-understand-relationship-how-to-find-child-relationship-name)

Comment: It works,  thank you!